# Fitting zero-truncated negative binomial to some datasets with VGLM fails

Tags: r, vgam

I've been trying to fit a zero truncated negative binomial to some count data. In some cases it works beautifully, for example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(VGAM)
df <- data.frame(n = 1:7, freq = c(0.32, 0.286, 0.19, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01))
fit = vglm(df$n ~ 1, posnegbinomial, weights=df$freq)
ggplot(df, aes(x = n, y = freq)) +
  geom_point(colour= "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = n, 
                 y = dnbinom(n, size=Coef(fit)[2], 
                             mu = Coef(fit)[1])/(1-dnbinom(0, size=Coef(fit)[2], 
                                                           mu = Coef(fit)[1]))),
                 colour = "blue")
```

[image: 1]

However, in other cases it fails:

```
df2 <- data.frame(n = 1:4, freq = c(0.87, 0.11, 0.01, 0.0005))
fit2 = vglm(df2$n ~ 1, posnegbinomial, weights=df2$freq)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = n, y = freq)) +
  geom_point(colour= "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = n, 
                 y = dnbinom(n, size=Coef(fit2)[2], 
                             mu = Coef(fit2)[1])/(1-dnbinom(0, size=Coef(fit2)[2], 
                                                           mu = Coef(fit2)[1]))),
                 colour = "blue")
```

[image]

In such cases a Poisson fit works fine:

```
fit_p = vglm(df2$n ~ 1, pospoisson, weights=df2$freq)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = n, y = freq)) +
  geom_point(colour= "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = n, 
                 y = dpois(n, Coef(fit_p)[1])/(1-dpois(0, Coef(fit_p)[1]))),
             colour = "blue")
```

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: your instance where it fails, it should be fit2 instead of fit1. can you write a proper function instead of copy pasting

Comment: ah my bad - have fixed

Comment: so, did this turn out to be a typo? If so, you can probably delete it ...]

Comment: Actually not quite - there was a typo, but I'm still confused as to why the NB fit is so much worse in this case than the Poisson fit

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you haven't mixed up something in your second model? I'm getting a much better fit. To avoid mistakes in repeating code, you may want to use a function for `y`, as I show you below:

```
library(VGAM)
fit1 <- vglm(df1$n ~ 1, posnegbinomial, weights=df1$freq)
fit2 <- vglm(df2$n ~ 1, posnegbinomial, weights=df2$freq)

## helper fun to get y
gy <- function(x) {
  cf <- Coef(x)
  dnbinom(seq(nrow(x@residuals)), size=cf[2], mu=cf[1]) / 
    (1-dnbinom(0, size=cf[2], mu=cf[1]))
}

## plot
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

plot(df1$n, df1$freq, main="fit1")
points(gy(fit1), col=2)

plot(df2$n, df2$freq, main="fit2")
points(gy(fit2), col=2)

par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- data.frame(n=1:7, freq=c(0.32, 0.286, 0.19, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01))
df2 <- data.frame(n=1:4, freq=c(0.87, 0.11, 0.01, 0.0005))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! You are correct, I had a bug in my code (fixed now in the main question). However, I'm still confused as to why the Poisson fit is near-perfect, while the NB fit is so comparatively poor. It was my understanding that NB should be able to approximate to a pure Poisson when appropriate (which in this case it appears to be!).

Comment: the difference is very striking, especially for my application which involves finding the chance that a value drawn from the fitted Poisson/NB is non-zero: for the Poisson fit this is 1-dpois(0, Coef(fit_p)[1]) = **0.22**, but for the NB it's 1-dnbinom(0, size=Coef(fit2)[2], mu = Coef(fit2)[1]) = **2.1e-12**

Comment: @OGW It seems to me that besides coding you also face statistical difficulties, for which this might be the wrong site. You could look into "Hurdle models" though. However, I'd advice you to ask the statistical part separately  at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where you are most likely to get competent answers from qualified guys.